# Shortcuts in the vim minibuffer

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In Vim, there is line at the bottom of the screen where commands are typed. IE

```
:q
:w
:help
```

etc

I call this the minibuffer, but this is probably the wrong term. My question is: When I am typing a long line in there can I use any shortcuts to navigate the text I'm entering. For example, if I enter

```
:e /hme/clumsyjedi/file.txt
```

And then I notice that I mispelled /home/ it would be great to go back to the start of the line using 0 or ^ rather than using the arrow keys to go back one char at a time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line at the bottom is called the command line. You can type

```
:help cmdline
```

and `Ctrl-D` to see a list of topics containing "cmdline". Unfortunately, there is no good way to discover that "command line" is abbreviated "cmdline" without already knowing something about Vim's help system.

```
:help cmdline.txt
```

will take you to the top of the help file `cmdline.txt` which contains all the help topics having to do with the command line.  The first section,

```
:help cmdline-editing
```

will tell you more about command-line editing including keys you can use for editing operations such as deleting the word before the cursor.

One of the most useful keys is `Ctrl-F` which will open a new Vim window containing the command line you've typed so far. You can then edit it using normal Vim commands. See

```
:help c_CTRL-F
```

Another really useful aid to editing the command line is to bind emacs editing keys to Vim's command-line editing functions. This is described under

```
:help emacs-keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a <kbd>Home</kbd> key on your keyboard, try using that.

Comment: Ctrl+B also works.